# C# - How to Suspend to RAM and wakeup

Tags: c#, sleep, standby, wakeup

I want to make a utility that will allow the system to use the Suspend to RAM feature and also have the ability to wakeup at a certain time.

Is this possible and how can I do this?

Code snippets would be great to look at.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step is to [use win32/wmi to set the system to wake up](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-3451405.php) at a specific time.

Second step is to [programmatically Hibernate](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial177_Lock-Stand-By-Hibernate-and-Log-Off.html) the machine.

google is your friend; c# wake hibernated system ;-)

Comment: lol. stackoverflow stopped me from doing that and i didn't care enough to find a way around it. thanks for the tip.... ;-)